# How are 2 very similar Graphql queries cached in Apollo client?

Tags: caching, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-cache-inmemory

I'm reading the Apollo client documentation but I am still confused as per how data is cached.

Let's say I have 2 queries that I use at a different hierarchy level in an app. Query **A** is used at the very top, while query **B** feeds a component several levels below.

If Apollo cache is configured `cache: new InMemoryCache()`, will **query B** use Apollo cached data from **Query A**, or not?

Same question if I were to use **Query A** for the top component and the bottom one.

**Query A**

```
  query MyProjectA {
    Project {
      id
      title
      budget
    }
  }
```

**Query B**

```
  query MyProjectB {
    Project {
      id
      title
    }
  }
```

Comment: you can explore cache behaviour using dev tools

Comment: Thanks, Ill check this out.